# ParaView crashes when loading a large ASCII VTK file

Tags: vtk, paraview

When I try to load a VTK file which is approximately 100mb in size in ParaView the program crashes. However, if I reduce the size of the file by selecting fewer data points (average size now approximately 30mb) it gets loaded without any problems.

I am not sure if it is something to do with memory management of Windows 7 OS. The system I am using is a Dell T7500, Xenon 2.65 GHz twin core, with 24 GB of RAM.

Comment: Can you post the code used to write the VTK file, it may be that your file format is not correct. Also, can you test reading the file on another system, to check whether it is the file or the system. Finally, try reading the same file with [VisIt](https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/visit/) if you can.

Comment: I have the same problem, it crashes in paraview but works in visit though extremely slow. Any suggestions? The file I use is around 315MB

Comment: what version of paraview are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a possible issue with paraview 64 bit ids.
If you compiled from source, make sure ***VTK_USE_64BIT_IDS*** is enabled.
If the pre-compiled binary it must be 64 bit.